# How to stop receiving LWT retained message?

Tags: mqtt, messagebroker, broker, paho, android-open-accessory

For testing, I have created a client with `clean sessin = false` and `setWill(WILL_TOPIC, WILL_MSG.getBytes(), 1, true);` and ran the App. Later, i set `setWill(WILL_TOPIC, WILL_MSG.getBytes(), 1, false);` when i run the App, i receive the previously reatined `LWT` messages. How to stop receiving them?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't receiving LWT messages as such, but a retained message. To clear a retained message, send a zero length retained message to the same topic. For example, with the Paho Python client you would do:

```
client.publish(WILL_TOPIC, payload=None, retain=True)
```

Comment: hi,do you think if the client called "disconnect", would that help to clear the "LWT" retained?

Comment: No, nothing apart from publishing an empty payload to the same topic will clear a retained message

Answer (score 0):

You could send a CONNECT message with “CleanSession=false” and “Will=true”, and sends an empty WILLTOPIC message

check [this](http://mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf) section 6.3

Comment: You linked the MQTT-SN specification which is different from standard MQTT, so this won't help the OP much. In case of MQTT-SN this will delete the WILL, though :)

Comment: how to do this it with paho js client